# addResource across multiple Chisel Modules while maintaining compile order

Tags: chisel

Working with Chipyard, I have multiple Chisel modules that rely on blackbox SystemVerilog files.

These files share common package dependencies and Verilator's strict compile order compliance results in undefined packages.  We are using the Chisel/FIRRTL generated file lists.

Let's assume the following example classes:

```
class ModX extends BlackBox {
  addResource("packageA.sv")
  addResource("packageB.sv")
  addResource("ModX.sv")
}
```

```
class ModY extends BlackBox {
  addResource("packageB.sv")
  addResource("packageC.sv")
  addResource("ModY.sv")
}
```

The following .f files are generated during the build with *.top.f being the focus of this issue:

```
firrtl_black_box_resource_files.harness.f
firrtl_black_box_resource_files.top.f
sim_files.f
```

It seems that FIRRTL enumerates the addResource list in reverse order, which can be accommodated by reversing the addResource order in the Chisel module.

Based on my experience, `firrtl_black_box_resource_files.top.f` would contain the following:

```
ModX.sv
packageA.sv
ModY.sv
packageC.sv
packageB.sv
```

I can tweak the order within the module and get the following:

```
packageA.sv
ModX.sv
packageB.sv
packageC.sv
ModY.sv
```

What I need, however, is to ensure that when redundant addResources are eliminated during elaboration, the "first" instance is kept, not the last instance.  As a result of the above example, Verilator will fail compilation because `packageB.sv` has not been compiled before `ModX.sv`

Does anyone know of a work-around?

Comment: I'd recommend filing an issue, the order here probably should be preserved (it is most other things). A workaround could be reverse the `.f` yourself, eg. `tac firrtl_black_box_resource_files.top.f >  firrtl_black_box_resource_files_fixed.top.f`

Comment: I have been able to modify my Chisel code to put all the packages (included via addResource) in the first module to be elaborated by the FIRRTL compiler.  Unfortunately, when I added a new module to the system, the elaboration order changed.... and the build broke (complaining about undefined packages).

Since I don't believe there is a way to control elaboration order, I think I am going to have to come up with a "cheat list" that explicitly specifies a list of packages and their required order.  That cheat list can then be used to sort the firrtl_black_box_resource_files.top.f